# How can I redirect R warning messages to STDOUT?

Tags: r, redirect, stdout, stderr

I'm using a grid engine to run R scripts. The STDERR is taken seriously under this setup, so I would like to keep it clean and have only real/serious/fatal errors printed to STDERR.

The problem is my R script generate various STDERR messages which are not really serious warnings... for example, `scan` seems to print to STDERR the number of items it read.

Can I redirect (from within R) STDERR to STDOUT?

Comment: this answer can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25307393/2490497

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the help page for `sink()`:

> ‘sink’ diverts R output to a connection.  If ‘file’ is a character
>     string, a file connection with that name will be established for
>     the duration of the diversion.
>
> Normal R output (to connection ‘stdout’) is diverted by the
>     default ‘type = "output"’.  Only prompts and (most) messages
>     continue to appear on the console.  Messages sent to ‘stderr()’
>     (including those from ‘message’, ‘warning’ and ‘stop’) can be
>     diverted by ‘sink(type = "message")’ (see below).

Comment: I know it's been a while, but for future people looking at this, I think that this answer may not work, since all errors are redirected when using type="message", even serioius ones. At least that's how the documentation sounds, and how it seems to work in my experience.

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  There is no way to globally change  *specifically the warning behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

@Dirk already provided the answer, but I would just add that you can use `stdout()` to get a connection to the STDOUT.  You can use this in any output function to direct output there.

Comment: No, that 'accepted' answer doesn't solve the problem - sink() can only redirect 'message', 'warning' and 'error' together, you can't segregate out just 'error'.

Answer (score 0):

One way to segregate out an error is to use try catch, in the main block everything is send to stdout, then any errors thrown by the code are caught and sent to stderr.

This will only handle errors that are thrown in the code, rather than logging of error messages, but might be a solution for you.

```
result = tryCatch({
    sink(stdout(), type = "message") # sink all messages, warnings, errors to stdout
    
    message('Starting! This message will go to stdout')
    warning('Warning! This message will go to stdout')
    error('Error! This message will ALSO go to stdout')
    
    #Call your code here, e.g.
    #...
    stop('An error is thrown', call.=FALSE)
    #...

}, error = function(e) {
    sink(NULL, type="message") # close the sink

    #Now sink closed, you can re-raise the error, and it will be directed to sterr:
    stop(paste0('Error: ', e), call.=FALSE)
})
```