# send R diagnostic messages to stdout instead stderr

Tags: r, stdout, message, stderr

Looking for an options which let me to redirect R diagnostic messages (produces by `message()`) to `stdout`, not `stderr` as it is by default.

`message` manual states:

> The default handler sends the message to the stderr() connection.

So the question is how can I change this default behavior? still leaving redirection of `warning()` and `stop()` intact.

Already tried sink `type='message'` but it redirects all (messages, warnings, errors).

If anyone is willing to test, this is sample script `exec_test.R`:

```
print("using print")
cat("using cat\n")
message("using message")
warning("using warning")
stop("using stop")
q("no")
```

which then will be executed by:

`Rscript exec_test.R 1>> exec_test.Rout 2>> exec_test_error.Rout`

I don't what to use `2>&1` because my script produce tons of `message`s and very rarely the real errors so I need to store those logs in separate files.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? When you run it can't you just add `2>&1` if you're logging it somewhere?

Comment: I can't believe that people don't see the benefit in wanting to do to this - having messages, warnings and errors all being sent to stderr and thus printed in the same colour in the R console means that you cannot spot actual problems in amongst potentially numerous diagnostic messages?!

Comment: I've been searching without luck to find the answer.  I'm in the same situation.  I want my stderr logs to be operationally meaningful, not whatever some random package author decided, but I don't want to just turn them off.  I want them reported in a more verbose log, just not stderr.

Comment: @jamie.f.olson you might always ask package maintainer for change `message` to `cat` + provide a link to this SO. Simply the `message` cannot be considered as a *message* if it goes to stderr, so it should not be used as a *message*.

Comment: 2023 and I am also looking for this feature. 
The thing is that "message" may no be meaningful as an error when integrating from external systems, I would want R messages go to stdout as well, because i rather not supress all messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is very likely not a best practice, you could override `message` with a version that writes to `stdout()` by default, right?

```
message <- function (..., domain = NULL, appendLF = TRUE) 
{
    args <- list(...)
    cond <- if (length(args) == 1L && inherits(args[[1L]], "condition")) {
        if (nargs() > 1L) 
            warning("additional arguments ignored in message()")
        args[[1L]]
    }
    else {
        msg <- .makeMessage(..., domain = domain, appendLF = appendLF)
        call <- sys.call()
        simpleMessage(msg, call)
    }
    defaultHandler <- function(c) {
        cat(conditionMessage(c), file = stdout(), sep = "")
    }
    withRestarts({
        signalCondition(cond)
        defaultHandler(cond)
    }, muffleMessage = function() NULL)
    invisible()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great code. It not strictly redirects `message` to `stdout` but it transform `message` to `output` which in case of `interactive` session is unwanted behavior. If there will be no better solution I will use this, maybe just insert the `if(interactive())` at the beginning.

Comment: That's because in an interactive session everything that goes to `stdout` is your `output`. ;)

Comment: This works when calling `message()` in the interactive console but not when libraries call `message()`. Is there some way of overriding this globally? I tried putting `@export` on the above definition of the `message` function but this had no effect.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sink`. Here's a modification of your code:

```
sink(stdout(), type = "message") # sink messages to stdout
print("using print")
cat("using cat\n")
message("using message")
warning("using warning")
sink(NULL, type="message") # close the sink
warning("after ending sink") # this will be the only thing in your err file
q("no")
```

Comment: Errors might occur in the various places in the script, how can I know where to `sink messages to stdout` and where to `close the sink`?

Comment: I would imagine you want the first line of my example to be the first line of your script. You can close the sink wherever you want; probably at the very end of the script.

Comment: If I close the sink at the end of script it will not redirect real errors (from stop()) to the stderr at all.

Comment: Try `sink(stderr(), type="message")` instead of `sink(NULL, type="message")`

Comment: but then any `message`s will not go to stdout but to the stderr, I want only error and warning to be redirected to stderr, and messages to stdout

Comment: @MusX I don't think that's possible without redefining the various message functions.

Answer (score 5):

The OP showed the execution happening via the Rscript command and using some I/O redirection. If you want to use redirection to log everything and only show to console on error, the best method I've found is to use `||` to check if the script had non-zero exit status before printing to screen:

`Rscript myrscript.R > temp.log 2>&1 || cat temp.log`

This method relies strictly on the exit code for printing, which only partly gets around `message()` going to stderr, but I thought this example helpful to mention since messages won't necessarily trigger a non-zero exit status and you can continue to log quietly with this method.

If you'd like to go one step further and keep appending to a single log file, then this will work:

`Rscript myrscript.R > temp.log 2>&1 || cat temp.log && cat temp.log >> persistent.log && rm temp.log`

The pseudocode for this command is:

1. Redirect `stderr` and `stdout` into temp.log
2. If command had non-zero exit status then write to screen
3. Then redirect the contents of temp.log into your persistent.log
4. Then remove temp.log

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a workaround and not the recommended solution but should be the best match to cover the exact need for question. Another way would be using C++ hooks but that is beyond me.

Using @bers code we can replace the the base R namespace function during your session we can change the behavior of Warnings and Messages in a global scope.

### Messages

We can create the function and then replace the base R function in names space using:

```
.stderr_message <- message
message <- function(...) {
  sink(stdout(), type = "message")
  .stderr_message(...)
  sink(NULL, type = "message")
}

assignInNamespace("message", message, "base")
```

Now we can test for messages:

```
# message go to stdout()
library("dplyr") ## this should redirect the mask messages to stdout
```

### Warnings

We can do the same for Warning messages, but for warning we should add the `immediate. = TRUE`, otherwise it will collect all messages and use another function (unknown by me), which will use the default sink to stderr.

```
.stderr_warning <- warning
warning <- function(...) {
  sink(stdout(), type = "message")
  .stderr_warning(..., immediate. = TRUE)
  sink(NULL, type = "message")
}
assignInNamespace("warning", warning, "base")
```

Now for warnings:

```
# warning go to stdout()
optFunc <- function(x) {
  abs(x^4 + x^2)
}
root <- optim(-1, optFunc)
```

But that will only work in function that are implemented using R's `base::warning`, not C warnings from `.Call` or `rcpp` since they call direct Warnings and Error Messages from the C interface instead of R env. An example:

```
## warning go to stderr()
as.numeric(c("1", "NA")) 

## this error and warning to stderr()
readRDS("noFile")
```

### Alternative way to deal with warnings:

We can set some global warning handlers and don't let them be printed to `stderr`.

```
options(warning.expression = quote(function() {}))
```

Then we create a handler to replicate the warning to stdout():

```
wn_handler <- function(cnd) {
  cat("Warning message: \n")
  if (!is.null(conditionCall(cnd))) {cat(format(conditionCall(cnd)), ": ")}  
  cat(conditionMessage(cnd),"\n")
  
}

handlers <- list(warning = wn_handler) 
classes <- names(handlers) 
.Internal(.addCondHands(classes, handlers, globalenv(), NULL, TRUE))
```

Now we can test our 2 previous example, and seem to work as intended:

```
# warning go to stdout()
optFunc <- function(x) {
  abs(x^4 + x^2)
}
root <- optim(-1, optFunc)

## warning go to stdout()
as.numeric(c("1", "NA")) 

## this error to stderr() and warning to stdout()
readRDS("noFile")
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining @Thomas and @branch14's answers into one, this is what I came up with:

```
.stderr_message <- message
message <- function(...) {
    sink(stdout(), type = "message")
    .stderr_message(...)
    sink(NULL, type = "message")
}
```

I verified this on the shell using this code

```
.stderr_message <- message
message <- function(...) {
    sink(stdout(), type = "message")
    .stderr_message(...)
    sink(NULL, type = "message")
}

print(1)
message(1)
```

Without my `message()`:

```
> Rscript bug.R 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
stdout: [1] 1
stderr: 1
```

```
> Rscript bug.R 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
stdout: [1] 1
stdout: 1
```