# R: Exit from the calling function

Tags: r

In R, is there a way to exit from the calling function and return a value? Something like `return()`, but from the parent function?

```
parent <- function(){
  child()
  # stuff afterward should not be executed
} 

child <- function(){
  returnFromParent("a message returned by parent()")
}
```

It seems `stop()` is doing something like that. What I want to do is to write a small replacement for `stop()` that returns the message that `stop()` writes to `stderr`.

Update after **G5W**'s suggestion: I have a large number of checks, each resulting in a `stop()` if the test fails, but subsequent conditions cannot be evaluated if earlier checks fail, so the function must exit after a failing one. To do this 'properly', I would have to build up a huge `if else` construct, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: You could have the child return a structure that includes a status flag.  With one status, the parent would continue.  With a different status,  the parent exits,

Comment: I don't see how that would be a good idea. It could make the parent's call of the child function logically opaque. It would be like a hidden goto statement. @G5W 's idea seems promising, and is much more logical.

Comment: Updated the question to address why I want to do this.

Comment: Again, at G5W's suggestion: You would write something like `if (attr(ans, "status") == "fail") return()` after each call to `child()`? Yes, that would work, but it seems awkward to write this again and again.

Comment: You could look more at R's error-handling facilities. What if the child function raises a custom error and you leave it to the parent function's caller to catch? (Not sure how that would work out in R but is easy enough in something like Python, so it should be possible). Alternatively, R makes it easy to modify an environment higher up the call stack, so you could directly modify the appropriate environment before stopping.

Comment: I am not sure but can `return(NA)` help?

Comment: "What I want to do is to write a small replacement for stop() that returns the same message" - `stop` doesn't return anything. Clarify what you mean.

Comment: Can you provide an inelegant working example that you'd like to simplify?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it. I guess I was looking for something like this:

```
parent <- function(){
  parent_killing_child()
  print("do not run this")
} 

parent_killing_child <- function(){
  do.call(return, list("my message"), envir = sys.frame(-1))
}

parent()
```

Thanks for all the advices.

Comment: this is neat.. I think if you implement the child function as `do.call(return, list("my message"), envir = as.environment(sys.frames()[[1]]) )` you can have it at any depth in the call stack..

Comment: In case someone has the same challenge as me and uses `source("parent_killing_child.R")`, then using `envir = sys.frame(1)` instead helps,...

Comment: and a second note, if one is on the nth parent function and `n` might be dynamic one can use: `do.call(return, list("my message"), envir = sys.frame(1 - sys.nframe()))`

Comment: This is excellent and extremely handy!  Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**: This sounds a XY problem, printing the stop message to stdout has few to no value, if interactive it should not be a problem, if in a script just use the usual redirection `2 > &1` to write stderr messages to stdout, or maybe use `sink` as in answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306819/send-r-diagnostic-messages-to-stdout-instead-stderr).

Now, if I understood properly what you're after I'll do something like the following to avoid too much code refactoring.

First define a function to handle errors:

```
my_stop <- function() {
 e <- geterrmessage()
 print(e)
}
```

Now configure the system to send errors to your function (error handler) and suppress error messages:

```
options(error = my_stop)
options(show.error.messages=FALSE)
```

Now let's test it:

```
f1 <- function() {
  f2()
  print("This should not be seen")
}

f2 <- function() {
  stop("This is a child error message")
}
```

Output:

```
> f1()
[1] "Error in f2() : This is a child error message\n"
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to **return a value** from the *parent*, rather than **throw a condition** from the *child*.

Comment: Well, OP was aimin at stop in original question, this answer would overwrite the stop exception by a simple print IIRC (been 5 years ago). (The fact there has been a lot of stop calls was the driver of this answer to avoid too much rewrites)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not running after the reputation points.

Comment: _"Don't worry, I'm not running after the reputation points."_ Given your 15k rep, I'm not surprised. **But for me, it's a matter of principle.** Also, newcomers should not be mislead, by the vote count, into devaluing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the parent function, make a list of tests. Then loop over the tests, and return your message at the first failed test. Subsequent tests will not be executed after the first failure.

Sample code:

```
test1 <- function(){criteria <- T; return(ifelse(criteria,T,F))} 

test2 <- function(){criteria <- F; return(ifelse(criteria,T,F))} 

test3 <- function(){criteria <- T; return(ifelse(criteria,T,F))} 

parent <- function() {
  tests <- c('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
  for (i in 1:length(tests)) {
    passed <- do.call(tests[i],args = list())
    #print(passed)
    if (!passed){ 
      return(paste("Testing failed on test ", i, ".", sep=''))
    }
  }
  return('Congrats! All tests passed!')
}

parent()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Kudos to [@chris](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2763073) for their clever application of [`do.call()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/do.call.html) in their successful [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41022662).

In five years since then, the R team has released the [**`rlang`**](https://rlang.r-lib.org) package within the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org), which provides the apt function [`rlang::return_from()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/return_from.html) in tandem with `rlang::return_to()`.

> While [`base::return()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/function.html) can only return from the current local frame,
> these two functions will return from any frame on the current
> evaluation stack, between the global and the currently active context.
> They provide a way of performing arbitrary non-local jumps out of the
> function currently under evaluation.

## Solution

Thus, you can simply do

```
child <- function() {
  rlang::return_from(
    # Return from the parent context (1 frame back).
    frame = rlang::caller_env(n = 1),
    # Return the message text.
    value = "some text returned by parent()"
  )
}
```

where the parent is identified via [`rlang::caller_env()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/caller_env.html).

## Results

When called from a `parent()` function

```
parent <- function() {
  child()

  # stuff afterward should not be executed
  return("text that should NOT be returned by parent()")
}
```

the `child()` function will force parental behavior like this:

```
parent()
#> [1] "some text returned by parent()"
```

## Bonus

See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70014517) for **throwing an *error* from a parent** (or from any arbitrary "ancestor").