# Throw Error From Parent Function (While Ignoring Child)

Tags: r, error-handling, callstack

## The Premise

I am designing a custom R function (call it `oedipus()`) to terminate its parent with an error.  Now obviously, a simple call to `stop()` *within* `oedipus()` will meet that requirement:

```
oedipus <- function() {
  stop("Ow, my eyes!")
}

laius <- function() {
  oedipus()
}



laius()
#> Error in oedipus() : Ow, my eyes!
#> 
#>   3. stop("Ow, my eyes!")
#>   2. oedipus()
#>   1. laius()
```

## The Twist

However, I want the error to appear as if it **originated from the parent**, rather than "bubbling up" from a child whose presence is noted in the call stack.  That is, I want the error attributed to `laius()` like so

```
laius()
#> Error in laius() : Ow, my eyes!
```

and ideally I would like `oedipus()` to be omitted from the call stack altogether:

```
laius()
#> Error in laius() : Ow, my eyes!
#> 
#>   2. stop("Ow, my eyes!")
#>   1. laius()
```

Is it even theoretically possible to design such a...***COMPLEX*** `oedipus()` function?

[image: 1]

Perhaps `oedipus()` could modify `laius()` with `evalq()` and `on.exit()`, such that the `laius()` will modify the call stack before it "dies" in turn?

## Bonus

Would it be possible to design `oedipus()` such that it can throw an error from any arbitrary (`n`th) "ancestor" down the call stack?

```
oedipus <- function(n) {
  # ...
  #  ?
  # ...
}

laius <- function(...) {
  oedipus(...)
}

labdacus <- function(...) {
  laius(...)
}

polydorus <- function(...) {
  labdacus(...)
}



polydorus(0)
#> Error in oedipus(...) : Ow, my eyes!

polydorus(1)
#> Error in laius(...) : Ow, my eyes!

polydorus(2)
#> Error in labdacus(...) : Ow, my eyes!

polydorus(3)
#> Error in polydorus(3) : Ow, my eyes!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom function `oedipus()` that leverages [**`rlang`**](https://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html) to target the given `n`th ancestor.

## Solution

The crux of the approach is the use of [`do.call()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/do.call.html) to "inject" a [`stop()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/stop.html) call as an "error thrower" at the front of the ancestor's [`on.exit()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/on.exit.html) "queue"; and then the use of [`rlang::return_from()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/return_from.html) to make the ancestor immediately trigger that error thrower.

**Note:** For the sake of stability, `oedipus()` is designed to preserve its ancestors' "exit queues".

```
oedipus <- function(n) {
  # Target the ancestor from which the error should be thrown.
  from_env <- rlang::caller_env(n = n)
  # Construct the error thrower.
  from_err <- rlang::expr(stop("Ow, my eyes!"))
  
  # Inject the error thrower into the ancestor's exit queue.
  do.call(
    what = on.exit,
    args = list(
      expr = from_err,
      # Preserve the existing exit queue...
      add = TRUE,
      # ...while injecting the thrower at the front; so the error occurs
      # immediately and is followed by the rest of the queue, just as if
      # 'stop()' had been called in the middle of the ancestor's body.
      after = FALSE
    ),
    quote = FALSE,
    envir = from_env
  )
  
  # Immediately return from that function (with an inert value), and so
  # trigger the error thrower.
  rlang::return_from(
    frame = from_env,
    value = rlang::expr(invisible(NULL))
  )
}
```

## Results

### Simple

With the ancestors defined as in the **Twist** section of your question

```
laius <- function(...) {
  oedipus(...)
}

labdacus <- function(...) {
  laius(...)
}

polydorus <- function(...) {
  labdacus(...)
}
```

then `oedipus()` will yield your desired results:

```
polydorus(0)
#> Error in oedipus(...) : Ow, my eyes! 

polydorus(1)
#> Error in laius(...) : Ow, my eyes!

polydorus(2)
#> Error in labdacus(...) : Ow, my eyes! 

polydorus(3)
#> Error in polydorus(3) : Ow, my eyes!
```

### Detailed

For illustrative purposes, let the ancestors of `oedipus()` be redefined with "exit queues" as below:

```
laius <- function(...) {
  # Test that the exit queue behaves normally.
  on.exit(cat("'laius()' should display this message on exit.\n"))
  
  oedipus(...)
}

labdacus <- function(...) {
  # Test that the exit queue behaves normally.
  on.exit(cat("'labdacus()' should display this message on exit.\n"))
  
  laius(...)
}

polydorus <- function(...) {
  # Test that the exit queue behaves normally.
  on.exit(cat("'polydorus()' should display this message on exit.\n"))
  
  labdacus(...)
}
```

Then `oedipus()` should yield the following results, with tracebacks shown:

```
polydorus(0)
#> Error in oedipus(...) : Ow, my eyes!
#> 
#>   5. stop("Ow, my eyes!")
#>   4. oedipus(...)
#>   3. laius(...)
#>   2. labdacus(...)
#>   1. polydorus(0)
#> 
#> 'laius()' should display this message on exit.
#> 'labdacus()' should display this message on exit.
#> 'polydorus()' should display this message on exit.


polydorus(1)
#> Error in laius(...) : Ow, my eyes!
#> 
#>   4. stop("Ow, my eyes!")
#>   3. laius(...)
#>   2. labdacus(...)
#>   1. polydorus(1)
#> 
#> 'laius()' should display this message on exit.
#> 'labdacus()' should display this message on exit.
#> 'polydorus()' should display this message on exit.


polydorus(2)
#> Error in labdacus(...) : Ow, my eyes!
#>   
#>   3. stop("Ow, my eyes!")
#>   2. labdacus(...)
#>   1. polydorus(2)
#> 
#> 'labdacus()' should display this message on exit.
#> 'polydorus()' should display this message on exit.

 
polydorus(3)
#> Error in polydorus(3) : Ow, my eyes!
#> 
#> 'polydorus()' should display this message on exit.
```