# Why is this R output not getting redirected?

Tags: r, bash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I like to run R scripts from the terminal (bash) using the command `Rscript`. I like to redirect my output to a file, for example:

```
Rscript some_R_code.R > output.log &
```

(I like to run it in the background, which is why I use &).

And, indeed, 99% of the output does go to that file. But I do get the odd little messages which do not. For example:

```
Warning message:
replacing previous import ‘getCall’ when loading ‘fBasics’
```

is outputted to the terminal, when I want it to the file.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You're only redirecting STDOUT. The warning message is being sent to STDERR. How you redirect STDERR that varies by shell (for bash see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21/818284#818284). Or, in R, you could redirect STDERR to STDOUT via [sink()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112896/how-can-i-redirect-r-warning-messages-to-stdout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You direct `stdout` to a file, but warnings actually go to `stderr`. You can redirect both `stderr` and `stdout` using `&>`:

```
Rscript some_R_code.R &> output.log &
```

Or you could redirect `stderr` to a separate file:

```
Rscript some_R_code.R > output.log 2> err.log &
```