# Report all errors combined in an R-script

Tags: r, debugging

I have a long a script. I was wondering if it is possible to report all errors that occurred after the the whole script is executed.

cheers

Comment: Please give us some more context. By "running", do you mean "source in RStudio" or "R on the command line" or "copy/paste into R session" or ...

Comment: Oh, yes sure! I use R from the command line. I copy all commands from a text file

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112896/how-can-i-redirect-r-warning-messages-to-stdout. Come back if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I think that is not really what I want. Basically what I like to have is a note at the end like: Number of errors: "x"

Comment: That's not what you asked. The answer to your original question is something like `sink(file=file("stderr.log", open="wt"), type="Message")` before your page and `sink()` after. If you want a count from that, perhaps you can parse the `stderr.log` (or whatever you name it) for lines beginning with "Error" (perhaps using functions such as `readLines` and `grep`).